# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

When I am using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` it doesn`t work and shows me the next error:

```
    SqlCommand newUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [DinoTable] VALUES(@name,  @height, @heightscale, @weight, @weightscale, @diet, @status, @locationDis, @dayDis, @monthDis, @yearDis, @yourlocation, @dayborn, @monthborn, @yearborn, @Gender, @yourEmail, @yoname, @lastname, @getmoney); ", c);
                newUser.Connection = c;
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", (string)Session["Name"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", Convert.ToDouble(Session["Height"]));
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@heightscale", (string)Session["HeightScale"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", Convert.ToDouble(Session["Weight"]));
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weightscale", (string)Session["weightscale"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diet", (string)Session["diet"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", (string)Session["status"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locationDis", (string)Session["locationDis"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayDis", Convert.ToInt32(Session["dayDis"]));
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthDis", (string)(Session["monthDis"]));
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearDis", Convert.ToInt32(Session["yearDis"]));
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourlocation", (string)Session["yourlocation"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayborn", Convert.ToInt32(Session["dayborn"]));
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthborn", (string)(Session["monthborn"]));
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearborn", Convert.ToInt32(Session["yearborn"]));
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", (string)Session["Gender"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourEmail", (string)Session["yourEmail"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yoname", (string)Session["YourName"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", (string)Session["YourLastName"]);
                newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getmoney", 0);
c.Open()
newUser.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
c.Close();
```

the full error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The parameterized query '(@name
>   nvarchar(5),@height float,@heightscale nvarchar(4),@weigh' expects the
>   parameter '@monthDis', which was not supplied.

Comment: Could it be the value is null?

Comment: no, I am setting it all from other pages

Comment: @PatrickHofman I tried your solutio and one of the session members wasnt good spelled, and now I have a new error:
**String or binary data would be truncated.**

Comment: You should specify the fields or add them in exactly the order of the columns in the database.

Comment: @OzCohen one of your nvrachar variables/parameters it to short for the value you're trying to put in.

Comment: String or binary data would be truncated: your field value is more long than definition field on table. Check defintion of your table

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the monthDis is a string and the yearDis and dayDis are integers.
Could it be that monthDis is also an integer?

If so, please try changing :

```
newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthDis", (string)(Session["monthDis"]));
```

to:

```
newUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthDis", Convert.ToInt32(Session["monthDis"]));
```

Comment: Could it be is more sort of comment